# SLAM in AUTOWARE using 3 VLP16

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, 3d-slam, vlp16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I want to SLAM in AUTOWARE using 3 VLP16s. I am trying to use Multi_lidar_calibrator. "Multi_lidar_calibrator" can calibrate only 2 lidars.

So I created a new ".lauch file" to use the 3rd lidar. And the code for using the third lidar was added to the "multi_lidar_calibrator.h" and "multi_lidar_calibrator.cpp" files.

In this way
void ROSMultiLidarCalibratorApp::PointsCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &in_parent_cloud_msg,
const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &in_child_cloud_msg,
const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &in_child_child_cloud_msg)

But

### /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:37: error:'void (ROSMultiLidarCalibratorApp::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void> >& , const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void> >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void> >&)' is not a class, struct, or union type
typedef typename F::result_type type;
......
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/multi_lidar_calibrator_lib.dir/src/multi_lidar_calibrator.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/multi_lidar_calibrator_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Failed <<< multi_lidar_calibrator [19.9s, exited with code 2]

Various errors appeared.

I want to know what process to follow to create a map file in AUTOWARE with 3 lidars.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366877/slam-in-autoware-using-3-vlp16/) by [jhhong2501](https://answers.ros.org/users/64548/jhhong2501/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, if Autoware.AI does not currently support this feature we cannot provide support for it. Additionally, Autoware.AI has stopped accepting new features and is now in "maintenance mode" (only accepting bug fixes and clean-ups). See [this discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/end-of-life-dates-for-autoware-ai/13750) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0